# Pressing a key multiple time in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a script which is used to insert data in a web form.There is some data in the form field initially, before inserting the new data i want to clear the field so that i can type new data.To achieving this I am using the multiple backspace.Is there any method by which i can press any key multiple time instead of writing the same code in multiple lines. Or any syntax which can simulate Ctl+A key which is used to select all.My code goes as follows

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
START msedge "https://fams.nabard.org:48443/PanaceaFAMS/login.faces"

timeout /t 6
!SendKeys! "{BACKSPACE}"
!SendKeys! "{BACKSPACE}"
!SendKeys! "{BACKSPACE}"
!SendKeys! "{BACKSPACE}"
!SendKeys! "{BACKSPACE}"
!SendKeys! "{BACKSPACE}"
!SendKeys! "{BACKSPACE}"
!SendKeys! "{BACKSPACE}"
!SendKeys! "{BACKSPACE}"
!SendKeys! "43569"
!SendKeys! "{TAB}"  
@end
// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this idea would make more sense to you. It should send each key as you've shown, but does so by executing `CScript` only once, which is much more efficient:

```bash
<!-- :
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "LURL=https://fams.nabard.org:48443/PanaceaFAMS/login.faces"
Set "Keys={BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} 43569 {TAB}"

Set "Edge=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
Set "Wait=%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe"
Set "CScr=%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe"

Start "" "%Edge%" "%LURL%"
%Wait% /T 6 /NoBreak 1>NUL
%CScr% //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf" %Keys%
Exit /B
-->
<Job><Script Language="VBScript">
    Set objArgs= WScript.Arguments
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    For Each strArg In objArgs
        objShell.SendKeys "" & strArg & ""
    Next
    </Script></Job>
```

Note, I have used VBScript above, as opposed to your chosen JScript. To do it using JScript, you could do it similarly:

```bash
<!-- :
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "LURL=https://fams.nabard.org:48443/PanaceaFAMS/login.faces"
Set "Keys={BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} 43569 {TAB}"

Set "Edge=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
Set "Wait=%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe"
Set "CScr=%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe"

Start "" "%Edge%" "%LURL%"
%Wait% /T 6 /NoBreak 1>NUL
%CScr% //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf" %Keys%
Exit /B
-->
<Job><Script Language="JScript">
    var objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
    objArgs = WScript.Arguments
    for (i=0; i<objArgs.length; i++) {objShell.SendKeys(objArgs(i))};
    </Script></Job>
```

---

Now to answer your specific question, you should be able to replace your nine 'Backspace' keystrokes with a single 'Clear the field' keystroke.

You'll see that I already replaced your `{BACKSPACE}` with `{BS}`, *(although `{BKSP}` works too, if you prefer)*, so just change:

```bash
Set "Keys={BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} {BS} 43569 {TAB}"
```

to:

```bash
Set "Keys={CLEAR} 43569 {TAB}"
```